Help with a circuit analysis problem
I have a circuit which gives me some strange results during simulation and I would like some help to analyse it. The circuit is the following:

Now, what I do is that I am watching the current values through R2 for different values of R1 when the input has some high voltage (e.g. 2V). For R1 values of up to ~5k I notice that the current through R2 is decreasing, but after that starts increasing again and then it gets stable. Could you help me understand why?
EDIT: Please disregard the transistor names. Just consider a "generic" nMOS and a "generic" pMOS transistor with a Vth of 0.7V.
The reason why I don't want to focus on the transistors is because they act only as switches. The input is an almost perfect square pulse (ramping takes 0,5 ns) with 200ns duration at 2V. I am talking about a single pulse, so there are no high-frequency switching effects or whatever. The capacitor emulates the capacitance of a transmission line, based on the info from a certain 45nm process.
Below is part of my simulation results. What you can see, is the current measured on the R2 branch for different values of R1.


You can't disregard the transistors and treat them as "generic". Their properties govern the circuit behavior and simulation results. Especially the "Vth of 0.7V" specification that's pretty low. Especially for a so-called generic transistor.

Also, you didn't describe the input: is it steady state? Or is it ramping? Because if it's steady-state, M1 and C2 are useless for the analysis.

Is C2 really supposed to be 35 femtoFarads? At that value it might as well be omitted altogether.

@MOSFET The transistors act only as switches. The input is an almost perfect square pulse (ramping takes 0,5 ns) with 200ns duration at 2V. It happens only once, so there are no high-frequency switching effects or whatever. The capacitor emulates the capacitance of a transmission line, based on the info from a certain 45nm process. On a side note, (and not referring to you) it would be nice if someone downvotes, to leave a comment about how the question could be improved.

@Arkoudinos Just add these infos in the question. Would like also a "view" of what you "have" as results ... and what you did.

@Antonio51 Thanks for that. I just did; hope this will help people understand it better.

The pMOS pull-up is connected via a C2, a 35 femto Farad cap. When M1 turns on, the cap is charged up to 800mV with a tiny bit of current through that 100 ohm pull-down. But we will see this only once. After that, the cap stays charged.
After the first cycle then:

M1 off, M2 on: output pulled down
M1 on, M2 off: charged cap is connected.

This will be true even if the 100 ohm is removed.
Another thing to check. Are M1/M2 thresholds set for 800mV Vdd? I suggest -400/400mV for M1/M2. Then they will turn on.
Anyway, here's a sim for you to try (simulate it here):

The cap shows 0pf, but it's 35fF. The main issue is the 1k pulldown which seems to swamp out any effect M1 and C1 might have.
Even if you remove the resistor load, once C1 is charged it never gets discharged so the voltage across it remains at 800mV. Maybe not what you intended.

Unfortunately the cap should be EVEN smaller; 35fF is kinda large capacitance based on the process data, and the length of the transmission line. M1 is a pre-charge transistor, essentially allowing the C2 to be charged. During the input pulse (actually ONE rectangular pulse), the pMOS should be switched off, nMOS switched on and I would expect to see some current from the discharging capacitor towards the ground. Or at least this is my intention...
